# Linux Shell Script error: 'Uexpected Redirection'

Tags: linux, shell, curl, openwrt

I have a Linux system running OpenWRT. I am trying to get a shell script to post to a remote server and then split the return string into an array. I get the following error when I try to run it: "line 18: syntax error: unexpected redirection" I know this has been asked before but all the solutions pointed to it being a bash syntax issue. So I changed "#!/bin/sh" to "#!/bin/ash" and have been unable to fix it. I am new to OpenWrt.

Script:

```
#!/bin/ash
#SetupScript
LAN_IP="$(ifconfig | awk 'FNR==31 {print $2}')"
SerialNo="$(cat /etc/config/example/ID/device_ID.txt)"
curl --request POST 'https://example.com/op_scripts/SetupRequest.php' --data "my_key=mykey" --data "serial=$SerialNo" --data "lan_ip=$LAN_IP"

SetupReply="$(curl http://example.com/resource)"

if [[ "$SetupReply" = *"false" ]]
then
echo 'setup_failure'
else
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=':'
read -r -a SetupVals <<< "${SetupReply}"

echo ${SetupVals[0]} > /etc/config/FilterWatch/network/curr_http_port
echo ${SetupVals[1]} > /etc/config/FilterWatch/RunTime/RemoteDatabases/db_name
echo ${SetupVals[2]} > /etc/config/FilterWatch/RunTime/RemoteDatabases/db_username
echo ${SetupVals[3]} > /etc/config/FilterWatch/RunTime/RemoteDatabases/db_password
echo 'completed'
IFS="$OIFS"
fi
```

Comment: You are using several `bash` features and trying to run it under `ash`.  Does your system have `bash` installed?  If so, replace `#!/bin/ash` with `#!/bin/bash`.  If not, you will likely need a rewrite.

Comment: No it does not appear to have bash installed. Would you recommend re-writing or installing bash?

Comment: Even with bash, the script has problems:  (1) The script, as is, tries to create an array `SetupVals` but the array is not used for anything.  Also, (2) The script is missing spaces around `[[` and `]]`.  Without knowing what the script is really trying to do, it is difficult to suggest a path forward.

Comment: I removed all the file writing commands from the post to try and make it easier to read. I edited the post and added them. The scripts writes the values of the array to various files. The objective of the script is to retrieve setup information from a remote database.

Comment: You are using `<<<`. This is syntactically incorrect in *ash*. See the [ash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ash).

Comment: @user3381715: May I ask what Linux system it is, that you don't have *bash* available? This is the default for all Linuxes I have met so far....

Comment: @user1934428 I'm running open OpenWrt. It's a form mainly found on routers. I changed it to just << and I now get the error: illegal eof marker for << redirection

Comment: Blindly changing one operator into another one will rarely result into a useful program. If you really want to use HERE documents, you have to provide a syntactically valid end marker (delimiter). I admit that the ash man page is a bit terse on this topic, but if you use a combination of letters of digits only, this would for sure make a valid delimiter.

Comment: @user3381715: You can find examples for here-documents [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). While they are written for bash, at least the aspects in this example relating to here-documentes should apply to ash as well.